# Turn On Versioning in SharePoint Online Add-In List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I want to turn on versioning for lists generated via a SharePoint add-in deployed to SharePoint Online. I've added `VersioningEnabled = "TRUE"` to the `Elements.xml` of each list, but still get `Vision History` is disabled:
[image]

My full xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Do not change the value of the Name attribute below. If it does not match the folder name of the List project item, an error will occur when the project is run. -->
  <ListTemplate
      Name="Departments"
      Type="100"
      BaseType="0"
      OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
      SecurityBits="11"
      Sequence="410"
      DisplayName="Departments"
      Description="My List Definition"
      VersioningEnabled = "TRUE"
      Image="/_layouts/15/images/itgen.png"/>
</Elements>
```

My Schema.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Departments" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Departments" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>

    <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01">
        <Folder TargetName="Item" />
      </ContentTypeRef><ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" /></ContentTypes>
    <Fields>

    <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Title;" Required="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" /></Fields>
    <Views>

    <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>

        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"></FieldRef></ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>

          <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View><View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>

        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef></ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>

          <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View></Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Am I missing something? Is it possible to turn on versioning for lists created via SharePoint add-in?

Comment: You should add `VersioningEnabled="TRUE"` in Scema.xml file. See this http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/12/sharepoint-2013-enable-versioning-in.html

Comment: I tried VersioningEnabled = True in the Elements.xml file, which is where list definition is stored. There is a Schema.xml file for each list in the project, but that is for metadata only (i.e. I get an error when I add a ListTemplate tag there)

Comment: There's a List tag in the Schema.xml file. Add the attribute in there.

Comment: I added it but Version Control is still disabled: `<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Departments" FolderCreation="FALSE" VersioningEnabled = "TRUE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Departments" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">`

Comment: Can you modify the list schema.xml as below and check - `<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Departments" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Departments" VersioningEnabled="TRUE" EnableMajorVersions="TRUE" MajorVersionLimit="5" MajorWithMinorVersionLimit="5" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">` ?

Comment: @GautamSheth the Version History control is still disabled with that XML string

Comment: Please try by having the attribute only in Schema.xml and not in Elements.xml file

Comment: Thanks @NadeemYousuf I tried that with the same result: control is disabled. Are you able to create a Sharepoint Add-In that deploys a list with Version Control enabled?

Comment: I've not tried that. But can you check if this works in farm or sandbox solution.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf Unfortunately I do not have an On-Prem server to deploy a farm or sandbox solution to